# CODEIGNITER - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: codeigniter

I know this has been frequently asked and has been answered a few times now but I can't fix my problem here using the ones that has already existed. I also just started to learn codeigniter. This is the code:

```
 $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
      $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
      $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));


      $movies = $this->movielist_model->get_movies();

      $data = result();

      foreach($movies->result() as $r) {

           $data[] = result(
                $r->title,
                $r->price,
                $r->rating
           );
      }

    // IT SAYS THAT THE ERROR IS HERE:

      $output = result(
           "draw" => $draw,
             "recordsTotal" => $movies->num_rows(),
             "recordsFiltered" => $movies->num_rows(),
             "data" => $data
        );
      echo json_encode($output);
      exit();
 }
```

Comment: You are missing `[` and `]` around your array syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `array()`

```
public function somefunction() {

    $output = array();

    $data = array();

    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));


    $movies = $this->movielist_model->get_movies();

      foreach($movies->result() as $r) {
           $data[] = array(
                'title' => $r->title,
                'price' => $r->price,
                'rating' => $r->rating
           );
      }

      $output[] = array(
            "draw" => $draw,
            "recordsTotal" => $movies->num_rows(),
            "recordsFiltered" => $movies->num_rows(),
            "data" => $data
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a array `$result` and put that into output array, if you have more outputs you can still put a lots of things inside that array.

```
  $result = [
          "draw" => $draw,
         "recordsTotal" => $movies->num_rows(),
         "recordsFiltered" => $movies->num_rows(),
         "data" => $data
  ];

  $output [] = $result;
  echo json_encode($output);
  exit();
```